# Convert attributes to elements if attribute value != -1

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSL to transform attributes to elements however I want to ignore if the attribute value !=-1. Here is an example XML

```
          <?xml version='1.0'?>
            <reportdata>
                <data>
                    <row>
                        <field colname='total'        
                               coltype='decimal'>-1</field>
                        <field colname='Id'           
                               coltype='Id'>10</field>
                        <field colname='startdate'    
                               coltype='Id'>10/01/2001</field>
                        <field colname='enddate'     
                               coltype='Id'>10/01/2001</field>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <field colname='total' 
                               coltype='decimal'>2000</field>
                        <field colname='Id'    coltype='Id'>20</field>
                        <field colname='startdate'    
                               coltype='Id'>11/01/2001</field>
                        <field colname='enddate'     
                               coltype='Id'>10/01/2001</field>
                    </row>
                </data>
            </reportdata>
```

I am using this XSL to transform the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />  
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="field">
         <xsl:element name="{@colname}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: seperate the @* template and type an xsl:if into it with test="not(normalize-space(.) = '-1')". that should do the trick. :)

Comment: Are you saying replace  <xsl:template match="@* | node()"> with  xsl:if ?

Comment: Expected output is <reportdata>
                    <data>
                            <row>
                            <total>2000</total>
                            <Id>20</Id>
                            <startdate>11/01/2001</startdate>
                            <enddate>10/01/2001</enddate>
                        </row>
                    </data>
                </reportdata>

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ignore if the attribute value !=-1
> I guess you only want to process it when the value is !=-1

I looked at it again and at my comment. I was confused since you called it attribute and attributes are @* elements.

The expected output helped me a lot, so please put it in for the next question.

Following code should ignore all field nodes which have the content '-1'.

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Edit: You said you want to ignore the row instead of the field -->
<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(text(field[@colname='total'])) != '-1'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="field">
    <!-- Alternative to '.' is to check for text() != '-1' which will concat all child::textnodes -->
    <!-- normalize-space() deletes beginning, ending and doubled spaces -->
    <xsl:element name="{@colname}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry Christian! If the attribute(colname[@total =-1]) then that row should not be processed. The entire row should be ignored. Your solution just ignores total but still prints the other elements.Based on my eg,  this row should not be transformed because total = -1 <row><field colname='total' coltype='decimal'>-1</field><field colname='Id' coltype='Id'>10</field><field colname='startdate' coltype='Id'>10/01/2001</field><field colname='enddate' coltype='Id'>10/01/2001</field></row>